# When win pc is connected to LAN router stops responding

Tags: lan

I've got a home network with a dozen of devices. Most of them connect over wifi, two PCs are on LAN. Now when I connect win8 PC to LAN, router stops responding on ping requests and all other devices can connect to each other, but not to internet. Removing LAN cable restores connection. Other PCs connected to the same LAN cable do not interrupt the connection. "Bad" PC connected to wifi does not interrupt the connection. It is clear that something's wrong with "bad" PC's NIC. The question is how to diagnose or possibly solve this?
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Just try to plugin a new NIC or have you already tried a new network cable? That are the first things i want to do. You can also try if you are able to ping yourself (To make sure that the TCP/IP stack is running correct)

Comment: It's better to ask this question on the Network Engineering or Super User sites, as it has no relation with programming/coding. Please check the description of the networking tag.